# Help with writing feedback

Tags: style, creative-writing, technique

I needed some help with feedback with my [writing](https://travelthroughoureyesblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/my-new-journey/). I am new to writing and would really appreciate if someone can read it and provide feedback. Any kind of tips and tricks or suggestion are welcome.

Thank you in advance. Happy writing :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are not a discussion board or a writers' circle. We require clear, answerable questions which have the potential to help others. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions we answer here. Critique questions are acceptable if carefully presented. You will get more direct help from a site like Critique Circle. http://www.critiquecircle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it would be helpful if you could post specific questions. I'll try to help when able, but otherwise I don't get reputation points. ;)

It's OK, you can post whole essays if necessary.

Comment: Writers does *not* allow people to post whole essays for critique. Please take our tour and see our help center as I posted above to see what this site allows.